# How to get the status of the pull request of an issue in jira via python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am not able to understand how to fetch the status of the pull request via Python jira API.
I have gone through https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html,
and searched the internet for it. But I was not able to link the jira issue with the pull request, I saw that the pull request is linked to jira issue id, but was not able to understand how to implement it.

I am using python 3.7

```
from jira import JIRA
issue = auth_jira.issue('XYZ-000')
pull_request = issue.id.pullrequest
```

I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: `str` object has no attribute `pullrequest`

I am not sure how to access pullrequest data in jira.
Any leads would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar with another python wrapper for the jira-API: [atlassian-python-api](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/index.html).
Look if it works in your case:

```
from atlassian import Jira
from pprint import pprint
import json

jira = Jira(
    url='https://your.jira.url',
    username=user,
    password=pwd)

issue = jira.get_issue(issue_key)

# get the custom field ref of the "Development" field (I don't know if it's always the same): 
dev_field_string = issue["fields"]["customfield_13900"]

# the value of this field is a huge string containing a json, that we must parse ourselves:
json_str = dev_field_string.split("devSummaryJson=")[1][:-1]

# we load it with the json module (this ensures json is converted as dict, i.e. 'true' is interpreted as 'True'...)
devSummaryJson = json.loads(json_str)

# the value of interest are under cachedValue/summary:
dev_field_dic = devSummaryJson["cachedValue"]["summary"]
pprint(dev_field_dic)

# you can now access the status of your pull requests (actually only the last one):
print(dev_field_dic['pullrequest']['overall']['state'])
```

Comment: is it possible to get the link to the pull request also?

Comment: The link isn't available in the Development field. You'll have to find another way.